# JavaScript Inner Anonymous Function Cannot Access Member?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to use anonymous function in JavaScript.  So I create anonymous function then I add the inner function, tigerInner() and in the function, I try to access the members in outer scope but I got error for undefined.

```js
var tiger = function(name, info) {    
    var name = name;//put this as private member
    this.behave = info;

    console.log("tiger: " + name + " " + behave);

    this.tigerInner = function(){
        console.log('name: ' + name);    
        console.log("tigerInner, behave: " + this.behave);//undefined error "this.behave"
    }
}

var test = tiger("tiger", "eating");
test.tigerInner();
```

Comment: pretty sure that you are not getting that error you know?

Comment: you're right.  the error is related to "test.tigerInner()" for undefined property.  thanks.  But how do I call the inner function?

Comment: There are already 3 answers, all of them are telling you how you can do that

Comment: thank you.  I didn't see the answers from others, too focus on the comment here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issues are:

1. You assign `info` to `this.behave` but then you use `behave` instead of either `info` or `this.behave`. Change `behave` to `this.behave` in your `console.log` line.
2. You wrote code that works like a constructor (assuming a newly constructed object as `this` and not returning anything) but you are not *calling* it as a constructor. To do that, you need to use the `new` keyword: `var test = new tiger("tiger", "eating")`.

---

Additionally, your line `var name = name` doesn't do what you think it does - it does nothing because `name` is already working like a local variable, and you just assign it to itself. So you can remove that line.

---

Here would be my proposal how the fixed code could look like:

```js
var tiger = function(name, info) {    
    this.behave = info;

    console.log("tiger: " + name + " " + this.behave);

    this.tigerInner = function(){
        console.log('name: ' + name);    
        console.log("tigerInner, behave: " + this.behave);
    }
}

var test = new tiger("tiger", "eating");
test.tigerInner();
```

An alternative without `new` would require using and returning a new object that you create yourself - just returning `this` as has been proposed in other answers will seem to work but actually put your `behave` and `tigerInner` properties into the global object and return the global object itself at the end (and will crash in strict mode). The `new`-less solution would look like this:

```js
var tiger = function(name, info) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.behave = info;

    console.log("tiger: " + name + " " + obj.behave);

    obj.tigerInner = function(){
        console.log('name: ' + name);    
        console.log("tigerInner, behave: " + obj.behave);
    };
    return obj;
}

var test = tiger("tiger", "eating");
test.tigerInner();
```

Comment: If you make a running snippet out of it I can remove my answer.

Comment: @CherryDT, thanks for your explanation.  I would like to keep the local variable "name" so i'm going to change it to "tigerName" so I wont get confused with function parameter "name".  Is it best practice to instantiate instance of the anonymous function rather the class?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your last question...

Comment: @Phil: Another common way is to prefix privates with underscore. Like `_Name` and `_Info`.

Comment: @CherryDT that question I was curious is it best practice to use "new" keyword to create new instance of the anonymous function rather using the "new" keyword for creating class object because in Java, C# and C++ that is what mainly used for "new" keyword.

Comment: You mean, as opposed to using the `class` keyword? Using an actual function as constructor (and assigning things to its `prototype` if desired) is the "old-fashioned" way from before `class` existed, and it still has its uses (and some people may actually prefer using it in general). The reason why I proposed `new` is because you wrote your function like you would write a constructor function, so this tiny change caused everything else to make sense.

Comment: Your part about *strict mode* is inaccurate.

Comment: @CherryDT yep yep, as supposed to use the word "class" instead of what i have here, anonymous function.

Comment: @JavaScript "Your part about strict mode is inaccurate." << Can you explain what you mean by that? Running `(() => {'use strict'; var tiger = function () { this.behave = 123 }; tiger()})()` gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'behave' of undefined` just like I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting that error, but instead you are getting one that is telling you that you are calling `tigerInner` on a `undefined` object, since `tiger` is not returning anything... instead you should return `this`:

```js
var tiger = function(name, info) {    
    var name = name;//put this as private member
    this.behave = info;

    console.log("tiger: " + name + " " + behave);

    this.tigerInner = function(){
        console.log('name: ' + name);    
        console.log("tigerInner, behave: " + this.behave);//undefined error "this.behave"
    }
    return this;
}

var test = tiger("tiger", "eating");
test.tigerInner();
```

Comment: @CherryDT i can't see where he asks for an instance of tiger

Comment: They don't but from the way they are calling `tiger` (without `new`) it's obvious that `this` will be the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode), and I can't think of any proper reason (especially in beginner code, not in some library that wants to do some trickery to get the equivalent of `globalThis`) why they would _intentionally_ want to pollute the global namespace and return the global object (or crash on assigning properties to `undefined`). So whatever their exact intent was, it was most likely not what your answer now proposes.

Comment: I wish I can check your answer for solution.  thanks.